# Editor adds same mistakes repeatedly

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I just got my edit privilege and started reviewing some edits.

I found some users making good edit suggestions but their edits repeatedly add the same mistake.

Examples:

- One user often adds spaces before punctuation characters.
- Another user changes "I" to "i".

Don't get me wrong, I appreciate what they are doing, but I'd like to know how I should handle this situation: Rejection does not seem fair because the rest of their edit suggestions are good, but approving also approves the mistakes.

Are reviewers supposed to <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> each of this edits reverting the mistakes they just made? Is there a possibility to notify the editors?

Comment: Flag these reviewers individually.  No need to drag their name(s) out in public.

Comment: @Makoto: Good, so how do I flag a reviewer? I don't find the button to do this, but I may well be overlooking it…

Comment: @siegi"  Use a custom moderator flag on a post that they've edited and explain what the issue is.  Don't forget to be thorough.

Comment: @Makoto: Thank you, I'll do this. One more thing: What should I do with this question now? As I said, I appreciate what they do and don't want to blame them, but I feel the examples illustrate the problem I have (had).

Comment: You can also try talking to them first. You can `@ping` an editor on one of the posts they edited.

Comment: So, there's this edit history, see...

Comment: For both those cardinal sins, I'd reject and improve, even if the rest of their edit is reasonable, both those are not acceptable where I come from, though they seem to be the style in some time zones east of GMT.

Comment: Re *"One user often adds spaces before punctuation characters."*: That is what [they have learned in school](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645) and have not yet unlearned. It will probably take several generations to unlearn.

Comment: Chances are they are simply slow typers, and run into a race condition often: someone else (2K+ rep) edits the post before them, fixing "i" to "I" and whatnot, and _after_ that, they submit their edit in which they didn't bother to fix that.

Answer (score 30):

If the suggested edit generally is good, but there's something that you could improve, click <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>. However, if the suggested edit introduces so many other problems that it's easier to start over, click <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>.

The rule of thumb is: **approve when the suggested edit does more good than harm, reject if it doesn't.** Whenever possible, make your own edit too, by clicking either <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> or <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>.

It's also a good idea to ping the editor on one of the post they edited and politely ask them not to make that mistake again (as [Laurel suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333269/6083675)).

I don't recommend flagging editors which makes such mistake. In most cases they aren't doing that on purpose. You should flag only in the last resort, when they don't respond to your comments and keep submitting edit suggestions with that mistake.

Comment: "*and keep submitting edit suggestions with that mistake*" - Definitely, and also keep an eye out for rollback wars, usually a good sign that at least one of the involved parties merits keeping an eye on.

Answer (score 16):

Before you escalate things, I suggest that you `@ping` the editor (on a post they've edited), and help them realize that they're making a mistake. It's possible they just weren't taught the [right skill](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4646/191178).

Of course, first make sure it's not just another "flavour" of English. I suggest including a link as proof (and a potential teaching source) in your comment.

If the edits are mostly destructive, or the editor refuses to change after being told, then you can flag for a moderator. Make sure that you include enough information, including links.